# Looping Procedure to Truncate a table SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create a database procedure to truncate a table, but if that truncate fails wait momentarily and re-run the truncate. I cannot lock the table or duplicate the table then drop the older table, so this more difficult method is my only option.

I am getting a PLS-00382 ERROR for my following code and stumped on the issue:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TRUNCATE_ROUTING_CACHE AS
runcount   NUMBER := 0;
status      varchar2(10);


BEGIN

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'truncate table routing_cache';


IF VALUE_ERROR THEN
status := 'FAIL';

    WHILE status = 'FAIL' AND runcount < 3
        LOOP
        sys.dbms_lock.sleep(120);
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'truncate table routing_cache';
          IF VALUE_ERROR THEN
             runcount := runcount + 1;

          ELSIF status = 'FAIL' THEN
             status := 'SUCCESS';

          END IF;

        END LOOP;

ELSIF runcount = 0 THEN
    status := 'SUCCESS';
    runcount := runcount + 1;
END IF;

END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't capture exceptions that way, you have to use the `EXCEPTION WHEN` construct. I'd recommend reading [Oracle's documentation on exception handling](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/errors.htm#LNPLS00701). I'm also very surprised you're looking for a `VALUE_ERROR`, this only covers truncation of numbers/dates during conversion or when being placed into variables. It doesn't cover tables.

All the requirements here are concerning; this really doesn't sound like your data model is correct; maybe something like a [global temporary table](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm) would be more appropriate?

However, if you actually need to do this then I'd simplify it as follows:

```
begin
   loop
      begin
         execute immediate truncate table routing_cache';
         exit;
      exception when others then
         dbms_lock.sleep(120);
      end;
   end loop;
end;
```

This loops infinitely. If no exception is raised during truncation it exits the loop, otherwise it sleeps for 120s.

Comment: Awesome, I tampered it a little to only run 3 times. I plan to add additional code to report the number of times it ran etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
In my opinion we should check for locks first. If lock is there then wait event should be invoked. I have pasted a snippet below which will help you to go in right direction. Let me know if this helps.

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TRUNCATE_ROUTING_CACHE
AS
  runcount NUMBER := 0;
  status   VARCHAR2(10);
  lv_cnt PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  --Checking first if any lock there on the object
  SELECT COUNT(1)
  INTO lv_cnt
  FROM V$LOCKED_OBJECT lc,
    ALL_OBJECTS obj
  WHERE lc.object_id  = obj.object_id
  AND obj.OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
  AND obj.OBJECT_NAME = 'ROUTING_CACHE';
  -- If lock present let it wait for 120 secs
  WHILE lv_cnt <> 0
  LOOP
    sys.dbms_lock.sleep(120);
    -- Again check foer the lock objects for any locks to continue loop
    SELECT COUNT(1)
    INTO lv_cnt
    FROM V$LOCKED_OBJECT lc,
      ALL_OBJECTS obj
    WHERE lc.object_id  = obj.object_id
    AND obj.OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
    AND obj.OBJECT_NAME = 'ROUTING_CACHE';
  END LOOP;
  -- Once lock clears up the Truncate command will be fired
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ROUTING_CACHE';
END;
```